# Emberjs with a Java REST backend

Tags: java, javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I am looking into Java (possibly Scala) for a project that will use Ember and ember-data.  I know I can write a backend to format the JSON, but I was wondering if there are any Java packages for Java more capable for building the JSON strings in a format that will utilize the  DS.RESTAdapter more effectively without building something completely custom?

Something similar to Rails Active Model Serializers would be ideal, or a JSON serializer and a  replacement REST adapter for Ember.

Just asking you all before I need to build something from scratch.  Thanks!

Comment: You know http://jackson.codehaus.org/?

Comment: I have not been a Java dev for about 10 years, so I am very much out of the loop.  I have seen JAX-RS mentioned, and the basic toJSON(), also I just found http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html  but I am doing basic research now, I may attempt to build a basic server this weekend if I can get an idea of wich libraries to try and implement.

Comment: Spring does the Job in our Application. If Jackson is found in the classpath, spring automatically uses Jackson to do the serialisation.

Comment: @Lilith2k3 Does Jackson's output format match what ember-data is looking for via DS.RESTAdapter?  Are there any customizations needed for this?

Comment: Yes and No. With Spring we are dealing with simple POJOs. So the structure of the output via Jackson is dependent on the POJO you created. So if you want [{name:"Doe", firstname:"John"}] you have to handover a List<Person> to Jackson. Hence Spring is MVC, you have a controller ( POJOs with annotations marking a class as Controller and annotations marking methods as endpoints) returning either a view (in our case JSPs) or data to serialize. So a possible method would be Public List<Person> showAllFriends() and Spring uses Jackson to produce the JSON output.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into any of the following frameworks or libraries to create REST APIs with java and/or scala:

- [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/)
- [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/)
- [Spray](http://spray.io/)
- [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/) (which uses Jetty, Jersey, and Jackson)

Comment: I would add [Grails](http://grails.org/) to that list. It's not Scala or Java, but if Scala is an option, Groovy (the language Grails is implemented in) is quite close. Grails doesn't have a native JSON API marshaller (yet), but neither do most of the other JVM frameworks.